# How to do passive perception checks in Marvel SAGA?

Tags: marvel-saga

I'm running a Marvel Saga campaign where one of the villains tries do fool the heroes. How do I run passive perception check? If I ask them to play a card, they will know something is up. If I use the fate card, I'm ignoring the hero's attributes and leaving it to chance, which I think is not fair, since one of the heroes have enhanced senses.

How do I play a passive check in Marvel Saga?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do a passive check is to keep track of your heroes attributes and factor them in whenever you use the fate card on their behalf.